# Calling function on each row of a DataFrame that requires building a DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to wrap some functionalities of the [lime](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) python library over spark ml models. The general idea is to have a `PipelineModel` (containg each phase of data transformation and the application of the model) as an input and build a functionality the calls the spark model, apply the `lime` algorithm and give an explanation for each single row.

**Some context**

The `lime` algorithm consists in approximating locally a trained machine learning model. In its implementation, `lime` just basically needs a function that, given a feature vector as input, evaluates the predictions of the model. With this function, `lime` can perturb slightly the feature input, see how the model predictions change and then give an explanation. So, theoretically, it can be applied to any model, evaluated with any engine.

The idea here is to use it with Spark ml models.

**The wrapping**

In particular, I'm wrapping the `LimeTabularExplainer`. In order to work, it needs a feature vector in which each element is an index corresponding to the category. Digging with the `StringIndexer` and similar, it's pretty easy to build such vector from the "raw" values of the data. Then, I built a function that, from such vector (or a 2d array if you have more than one case), create a Spark `DataFrame`, apply the `PipelineModel` and returns the model predictions.

**The task**

Ideally, I would a like to build a function that does the following:

1. process a row of an input `DataFrame`
2. from the row, it builds and collect a `numpy` vector that works as input for the lime explainer
3. internally, the lime explainer slightly changes that vector in many ways, building a 2d array of "similar" cases
4. the above cases are transformed back as a Spark DataFrame
5. the `PipelineModel` is applied on the above `DataFrame`, the results collected and brought the lime explainer that will continue its work

**The problem**

As you see (if you read so far!), for each row of the `DataFrame` you build another `DataFrame`. So, you cannot define an `udf`, since you are not allowed to call Spark functions inside the `udf`.

So the question is: how can I parallelize the above procedure? Is there another approach that I could follow to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can still use udfs in this case, followed by `explode()` to retrieve all the results on different lines. You just have to make sure the input column is already the vector you want to feed lime.

That way you don't even have to collect out of spark, which is expensive. Maybe you can even use vectorized udfs in your case to gain speed(not sure)

```
def function(base_case):
    list_similarCases = limefunction(base_case)
    return list_similarCases

f_udf = udf(function, ArrayType())

df_result = df_start.withColumn("similar_cases", explode(f_udf("base_case")))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that is not a matter of `explode`. You get an error applying `f_udf` if such function calls spark functions (as it is in this case).

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. In my example f_udf does not execute any spark unless the limefunction does, in which case you should split the function in spark/python parts.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of my post. The `limefunction` does indeed call spark functions. It's where my problem lies. I cannot split as you say, since the `lime` function needs to call the spark model in order to do its job.

Comment: Okay ! Then the question is how to pass the Spark model to python, or how to transform the whole `limefunction` into sparksql.

For the first I have no idea. For the second it's probably really complicated to adapt python code to sparksql. So understanding the lime lib logic and implementing it yourself may be the only solution.